# d3 tick mark spacing between line and text

Tags: d3.js

**I found the solution, you need to modify the axis:**

```
viz.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - 200) + ")")
    .call(xaxis)
    .selectAll("text") 
    .attr("y", "10px"); //set y padding here
```

I would like to have a minimal axis layout. Just the horizontal line and the text below. No tick marks.

I set the tickSize to zero but this puts the text directly below the line. How do I control the spacing between the line and the text?

Thanks.

```
var xaxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xpos)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%Y'))   
    .tickValues([minDate, maxDate])
    .tickSize(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ticks to zero when defining the xaxis:

```
var xaxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xpos)
  .ticks(0)
  .orient("bottom");
```

A complete example can be found here:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2996766

Comment: Yes this is true however if you don't set the y padding the text will be uncomfortably close to the axis.